# remove repeatation in jplayer playlist?

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I am using jplayer with the following code to add song into the playlist.

```
myPlaylist.add({
  title:"Tempered Song",
  artist:"Miaow",
  mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.mp3",
  oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-01-Tempered-song.ogg",
  poster: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/poster/Miaow_640x360.png"
});
```

Using the given code it add the song into the playlist successfully but now the problem is that it add the same song multiple times too.but i want it unique, it shouldn't be duplication of song list.how can i prevent this issue?

Comment: Just Compare with .mp3 url.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the data of playlist into the myPlaylist->playlist. compare the mp3 url before adding song to your playlist. if mp3 url not foung into the  myPlaylist->playlist add track into the playlist not other wise.

Answer (score -1):

also agree with above answer,

You can compare your `mp3 url with  myPlaylist->playlist` data list.